# Take every second element from array in as3

Tags: actionscript-3

I am making my first as3 game and am taking a username and password field from a MySQL server. The array gets split into each user, but I would also like to split it from username to password. I am then checking if the username and passwords from the database and user input match.

I have programmed everything besides the splitting of username and password, and am happy for any suggestion into the right direction.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show us what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Use the filter method of the Array class](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html#filter%28%29), which

> [e]xecutes a test function on each item in the array and constructs a new array for all items that return true for the specified function.

The test function that's passed to the filter method should have this signature

> function callback(item:*, index:int, array:Array):Boolean;

Given the index of the element, you can figure out if it is one of every second element with the modulo operator %.

Comment: up for not posting code but explanation - love that! :) most people just copy-paste and not even think..

Comment: given that the PO doesn't even bother asking a question but simply states what he wants, I'm guessing an explanation is not what he was hoping for.

Comment: And that's exactly why he must get explanation **AND** flag for not asking questions properly!

Comment: Thank you so much. I am sorry I came of pushy and kinda annoying. I'm 12 and have just transitioned from as2 to as3 and am happy that you pointed me into the right direction. :)